# Get user's installation path from distutils

Tags: python, python-2.6, distutils

I want to use `disutils` to make a `.msi` for my python library. Before installation, the user can choose the destination path of the installation. Depending on this path, I want to generate a `.pth` file that will contain the chosen path. For this to be possible I need to run a post-installation script that will place the `.pth` in the correct place.

My question is: Is there a way of getting that installation path that was selected by the user, during run-time?

Answer (score 0):

Can’t you use a relative path in the .pth file?  Or avoid using a .pth file at all?  (They’re used for module collections that pre-date packages in Python, or horrible import hacks.)